# How to: dynamic inline-block elements to start a new line when the container width is reach

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

EDIT** I forgot to set the width of the container

I am building a MVC webapp and I have a @foreach(var item in collection) loop that create a inline-block div (because I want them to display next to each other). My problem is that the loop is based on the user connected so the number of created div is not always the same and past a certain amount it will overflow outside the container. Is there a way (or what is a good way) too make it that when the container width is reach, the next dynamic div will be on a new line?

thx to anyone that could help and have a good day.

Comment: That actually should be the default behavior of inline-block elements inside a block element with a set width; when their total width is too much, they will move to the next line. Can you give an example of a situation where this doesn't work?

Comment: My god, this was all my bad, I rewrote the container class and forgot to set a width *facepalm*. Thx for waking me up haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem about this. 

display:inline-block can do it.

For this, you can set any width to your container and make the height auto.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {width:100%;height:auto;}
.content {width:50px; height:50px;background:red; display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

Lastly, you just do your foreach and whatever to append. Just duplicating the .content div and see. Hope it helps

It doesn't matter whether the .content div will be different size. Most importantly, you have to set vertical-align:top because inline-block if the element are of different height. It will not be the same alongside each other.

Inline-block can pretty much display like Pinterest without any javascript. Cheers

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinli/xd3hsuvm/3/)